# Backbone delete command executes on the Node server but no sync event is fired on the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

After issuing delete command from Backbone sync, I am not getting sync event although Node server executes the command and deletes an entry from MongoDB. This is the relevant code on the frontend (Backbone):

```
handleDeleteCar: function (carId) {
  Backbone.sync("delete", cars.get(carId), {url:'/api/cars/' + carId});
  cars.remove(cars.get(carId));
},
```

and on the backend (Node):

```
app.delete('/api/cars/:id', function (req, res) {
  var carImage = Car.findById(req.params.carId)._carImage;
  Car.remove({ _id : req.params.id } , function (err){
    if (!err){
      console.log("Cars deleted");
      Image.remove({_id:carImage},  function (err){
        if (!err)
          console.log("Image deleted");
        res.json({"status":"O.K."});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

As I said everything works fine except I am not getting a sync event in the browser. I am getting this event for every other verb I am using (get, post and put). I tried with different return values from the server, but to no avail.

Comment: The docs for [sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) are pretty ambigious about what kind of event will get emitted. It's unclear if their referring to the collection [sync method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sync) or the sync [event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog). Try listening for a **remove** event and if that fails try listening for **all** and see what events actually get emitted.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using Backbone.sync directly.
The correct way to do this is to set the collections `url` to '/api/cars/' and call `model.destroy()`:

```
var Cars = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/cars/',
  /* ... */
});

/* ... */
handleDeleteCar: function (carId) {
  cars.get(carId).destroy()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did on this way and everything works fine, except my problem still persists... I'll check all the HTTP headers to see what's actually going on.